# BeautifulSoup - get attributes on the div's I'm iterating over

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse lists of companies from VC websites.  I've found the right elements to iterate over, but I can't seem to get data on those elements themselves.

Here's the sample HTML I'm going through:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <main id="primary" class="content-area" role="main">
        <header class="page-header">
        <main id="portfolio-landing-company-list" class="page-content">
            <section id="portfolio__list--grid" class="portfolio__list--all">
            <div class="company company-stage--venturegrowth company-type--enterprise company--single-company">
                    <div class="company__thumbnail company__thumbnail-link">
                        <a href="http://www.domain1.com" title="Company1" target="_blank">
                    </div>      
            </div>
            <div class="company company-stage--seed company-type--bio company--single-company">
                    <div class="company__thumbnail company__thumbnail-link">
                        <a href="http://www.domain2.com" title="Company2" target="_blank">
                    </div>
            </div>
```

This is how I'm currently using BeautifulSoup and **this part is working great**:

```
portfolio = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'portfolio-tiles'})
for eachco in portfolio.find_all('article'):
  companyname = eachco.a['title']
  companyurl = eachco.a['href']
```

**But what I want to do is grab the class elements from here**:

```
<div class="company company-stage--venturegrowth company-type--enterprise company--single-company">
or
<div class="company company-stage--seed company-type--bio company--single-company">
```

(there are multiple variations for each company in the list)

I've tried iterating through with:

```
portfolio = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'portfolio-tiles'})
for eachco in portfolio.find_all('article'):
  companyattributes = eachco.div['class']
```

but that spits out rows of:

```
['company__thumbnail', 'company__thumbnail-link']
```

(aka, a level below what I'm looking for)

**How can I iterate over all of the results but get class elements for each result?**  I sense I'm missing something really basic, but would appreciate any help figuring out what that thing is!

**UPDATE**

I ended up going with the following, which got everything working together:

```
portfolio = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile("company company-"))
    for eachco in portfolio:
        coname = eachco.a['title']
        courl = eachco.a['href']
        cotypes = eachco['class']
        costage = cotypes[1]
        comarket = cotypes[2]
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: I'd like to get ['company','company-stage--venturegrowth', 'company-type--enterprise', 'company--single-company'] in addition to the URLs/Names which I'm already getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module to find particular text in class element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """<html><div id="content" class="site-content">
    <main id="primary" class="content-area" role="main">
        <header class="page-header">
        <main id="portfolio-landing-company-list" class="page-content">
            <section id="portfolio__list--grid" class="portfolio__list--all">
            <div class="company company-stage--venturegrowth company-type--enterprise company--single-company">
                    <div class="company__thumbnail company__thumbnail-link">(
                        <a href="http://www.domain1.com" title="Company1" target="_blank">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="company company-stage--venturegrowth company-type--enterprise company--single-company">
                    <div class="company__thumbnail company__thumbnail-link">
                        <a href="http://www.domain2.com" title="Company2" target="_blank">
                    </div>
            </div> </html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div' ,class_=re.compile("stage"))
for div in divs:
    print(div['class'])
```

Output :

```
[u'company', u'company-stage--venturegrowth', u'company-type--enterprise', u'company--single-company']
[u'company', u'company-stage--venturegrowth', u'company-type--enterprise', u'company--single-company']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can already successfully get the names/URLs.  I'm looking to get the class elements from the div, like: ['company','company-stage--venturegrowth', 'company-type--enterprise', 'company--single-company']

Comment: This works only if word 'stage' is in div class @KajalKundu

Comment: You can search any unique text exists inside the class.

Comment: According to the example we can search here ‘enterprise’ or ‘bio’ that would give unique result.instead of find_all then need to use find.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** this is what you're looking for:

```
for i in range(len(soup)):
     print(soup.select('div[class*="stage"]')[i].attrs['class'])
```

Output

```
   ['company', 'company-stage--venturegrowth', 'company-type--enterprise', 'company--single-company']
   ['company', 'company-stage--seed', 'company-type--bio', 'company--single-company']y--single-company']
```

Comment: Ah, that seems to find the class elements for the first company in the list, and I see now my sample HTML above doesn't show how each company's <div> is different. There's also <div class="company company-stage--seed company-type--bio company--single-company"> and many other variations.  As I iterate through the list I want to grab the unique set of elements for each company

Comment: Got it; try now.